# is there a way to verify Excel PIA install

Tags: excel, office-pia

How do I know if excel PIA is installed on a system ? One of our users who is trying to install our excel addin and getting error message "A required component for interacting with Excel 2007 is not available". This is happening because the Launch condition check "HASEXCELPIA" is failing. I am not able to figure out how do I explicitly check if Excel PIA is installed on a system. Any location in "Program Files" or is there any Registry entry which  is helpful in finding out whether the PIA is installed. I wanted to know this so that I can guide the user to check and see if its there already or guide him to install by downloading the PIA. I just dont want to ask him to install and screw up anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find the PIA at the following location: C:\Windows\assembly

Here you can find the respective PIA installed for every office application such as Excel, PowerPoint , etc. and for every version.

You can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/15s06t57%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link for versions.

Thanks.

Comment: @ravi- You don't have to ask the user to manually check for the PIA. You can just change this "A required component for interacting with Excel 2007 is not available" to a suitable message and redirect the user from the message pop-up directly.